# Getting Models back in Json- parsing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

How to get the Model from these 2 similar Json Results :
I tried various ways but still can't figure it out.
thanks in advance...

```
eg : result.ImagePath
```

1.

```
{"Success":"True"ImagePath":"D:\Wyo\PH\TS\Images\Preview\Admin\Toy\Soli.jpg"}
```

"2.

ContentResult passed as Json

```
Content="{"Success":"True"ImagePath":"D:\Wyo\PH\TS\Images\Preview\Admin\Toy\Soli.jpg"}"


Controller's sent data :

    ContentResult result = Content("{\"Success\":\"" + vm.Success + "\"ImagePath\":\"" + vm.ImagePath + "\"}");
    result.ContentType = "application/json"; //-- "application/json" //- "text/plain"

    JsonResult jsResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsResult; //result
```

Comment: what is your expected output ? Do you want to convert your JSON to class object ?

Comment: Just want to get the ImagePath out of this response (json)

Comment: It should be easy for frequent json user, not looking for binding , ko or such a thing here, both properties here are simple string which is passed as json.

Comment: If it's a bit strange that's for learning process. how to make it work, don't want to change the structure, if there isn't any formatting error help me on casting it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON content looks like this

```
{
    "Success": "True",
    "ImagePath": "Images/Preview/Admin/Toy/Soli.jpg"
}
```

You should be able to read it like this

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("ImgPath","Home")",function(data){   
   alert(data.ImagePath);
});
```

This should work if you have an action method called `ImgPath` in your `Home` controller which returns the JSON in the above format.

Here is a working sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/jpQb4D

**Note :** You should not be returning the physical path to the image ( D://Wylix ....). You should be returning the relative/absolute url to the image and use that.

Comment: Dude the data is sent via the controller, we don't know what are they, but they are simple strings and we don't want to cast them, I posted sample generated json, know how can I deal with it to get the posted info? simple $.parseJSON didn't work here.

Comment: Why are you returning string from your controller when it can return proper JSON  ?

Comment: I've got the json so not looking to get it again, just want to play with the result, let me post the sample code in the controller, if the json's format there is wrong, or you know a better way to get the data out of it let me know...

Comment: It's proper Json, but I couldn't cast it in this example, don't know where is wrong, the property in the controller was string, and I want to know that in javascript. my parsing mechanism or the format of the sent data could be wrong. so I asked for a proper parsing strategy here, wait a minute to let me aff the formatted string in the controller

Comment: added more info and the posted data

Comment: @LastBye Check the sample fiddle i added to the answer.

Comment: Understand, I try to follow your tips, but can you please letting me know what is the problem here, that I can't parse this simple data, this is for my learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JSON.NET? If you use that with json2csharp you should be good to go.

Using json2csharp I get the following class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Success { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Then to get the class filled in from the string you could do something like this:

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Does that help?